# Alignment of icons within bootstrap header

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

https://jsfiddle.net/5nj5nmqz/3/

```
<h1 class="page-header row">
      Header
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
              Export spreadsheet
              <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 form-group has-feedback">
          <input type="text" class="form-control search pull-right" placeholder="Search by check name...">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      </div>
</h1>
```

Having a bit of trouble getting the elements within the header to align correctly, as well as getting a bootstrap glyphicon icon to line up inside the input field.

Any ideas on how this could be done correctly? I tried wrapping in rows and moving the columns, but it seems to be off every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<h1 class="page-header">Header</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default pull-right export">
            Export spreadsheet
            <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 form-group has-feedback pull-right">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="text" class="form-control search pull-right" placeholder="Username" />
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Few things to note:

`<h1 class="page-header row">` is wrong. When using the bootstrap `col`s, you should create a row by simply saying `<div class="row">`.

Bootstrap can have 12 columns per row I think. If you are designing the row-column way, the correct way is to create a `<div class="row">` and it's children should be `<div class="col-**-n">` where the n's of all children add up to 12.

Comment: Ah, the reason I tried to include the row in the header is because I want to have all the elements inline with the header. Your code gets close, but seems to place them underneath the header. I tried to wrap the header with a row tag, but this also seems to break the design...